# How to safely update the GUI of a JavaFX application from a background thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I am trying to write the Asteroids game using **JavaFX 2.2** but I'm running into problems when I try to move the game objects(i.e. the rocks, space ship and beams) or detect collisions between them.

Initially I tried to do all the moving and collision detection from a background thread using the **scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable, long, long, TimeUnit)** method of the **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** class but this was causing terrible run time exceptions that wasn't even in my code because I was trying to modify the GUI form a background thread.

My next approach was to update the game objects from a the UI thread itself using the **AnimationTimer** class. While this approach solved the exceptions' problem, being run on the UI thread, it's causing significant lags.

So, I want know if there's a feasible way to update the game objects without causing exceptions or lags?

Here is the Main class of my application:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Application {
    private ArrayList<Rock> rocks = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Beam> beams = new ArrayList<>();
    private SpaceShip spaceShip = null;
    private Group group;
    private final int SCENE_WIDTH = 900, SCENE_HEIGHT = 600;
    private final int ROCK_COUNT = 20;
    private boolean upKeyPressed, upKeyReleased, zKeyPressed, leftKeyPressed, rightKeyPressed;
    private int bulletsFired = 0, skipCount = 10;
    private AudioClip explosion = new AudioClip(Main.class.getResource("explosion.wav").toString());
    private AudioClip destroy = new AudioClip(Main.class.getResource("destroy.mp3").toString());

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ImageView spaceBackground = new ImageView("space.jpg");
        spaceBackground.setFitHeight(SCENE_HEIGHT);
        spaceBackground.setFitWidth(SCENE_WIDTH);

        group = new Group(spaceBackground);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);

        initializeGameObjects();

        // add event listeners for the spaceShip controls
        scene.setOnKeyPressed((keyEvent) -> {
            switch(keyEvent.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    upKeyPressed = true;
                    break;
                case Z:
                    zKeyPressed = true;
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    leftKeyPressed = true;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    rightKeyPressed = true;
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased((keyEvent) -> {
            switch(keyEvent.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    upKeyPressed = false;
                    upKeyReleased = true;
                    break;
                case Z:
                    zKeyPressed = false;
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    leftKeyPressed = false;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    rightKeyPressed = false;
            }
        });

        AnimationTimer updater = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                updateGameObjects();
            }
        };

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Asteroids");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResource("icon.png").toString()));
        primaryStage.show();

        updater.start();
    }

    private void initializeGameObjects() {
        // initialize the Rock ArrayList
        for(int i=0; i<ROCK_COUNT; i++) {
            Rock rock = new Rock();
            rocks.add(rock);
            group.getChildren().add(rock);
        }

        // add the space ship to the center
        spaceShip = new SpaceShip();
        group.getChildren().add(spaceShip);
    }

    private void updateGameObjects() {
        // move the rocks
        for(Rock rock: rocks) {
            rock.move(rocks);
        }

        // check for collision among rocks
        for(int i=0; i<rocks.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<rocks.size(); j++) {
                Rock rock1 = rocks.get(i), rock2 = rocks.get(j);

                // if two rocks collide, interchange their speeds
                if(rock1.getBoundsInParent().intersects(rock2.getBoundsInParent())) {
                    int tmpSpeedX = rock1.getSpeedX();
                    int tmpSpeedY = rock1.getSpeedY();

                    rock1.setSpeedX(rock2.getSpeedX());
                    rock1.setSpeedY(rock2.getSpeedY());

                    rock2.setSpeedX(tmpSpeedX);
                    rock2.setSpeedY(tmpSpeedY);
                }
            }
        }

        // control the spaceShip
        if(upKeyPressed) {
            spaceShip.accelerate();
            //System.out.println(spaceShip.getSpeed());
        }
        else if(upKeyReleased) {
            if(spaceShip.getSpeed() > 0)
                spaceShip.decelerate();
            else {
                spaceShip.nullifySpeed();
                upKeyReleased = false;
            }
            //System.out.println(spaceShip.getSpeed());
        }

        if(leftKeyPressed)
            spaceShip.rotateLeft();
        if(rightKeyPressed)
            spaceShip.rotateRight();
        if(zKeyPressed) {
            if(bulletsFired < 4) {
                beams = spaceShip.fire(group);
                bulletsFired++;
                skipCount = 15;
            } else {
                skipCount--;

                if(skipCount == 0)
                    bulletsFired = 0;
            }
        }

        // move the beams
        for(int i=0; i<beams.size(); i++) {
            Beam beam = beams.get(i);

            if(!beam.isAlive()) {
                beams.remove(beam);
                continue;
            }

            beam.move();
        }

        // check if the ship hits a rock
        for(int i=0; i<rocks.size(); i++) {
            Rock rock = rocks.get(i);

            if(Shape.intersect(spaceShip, rock).getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 0) {
                rock.setVisible(false);
                rocks.remove(rock);
                explosion.play(0.04, 0, 1.5, 0, 1);
            }
        }

        // check if a beam hits a rock
        for(int i=0; i<beams.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<rocks.size(); j++) {
                Beam beam = beams.get(i);
                Rock rock = rocks.get(j);

                if(Shape.intersect(beam, rock).getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 1) {
                    rock.setVisible(false);
                    rocks.remove(rock);
                    beam.setVisible(false);
                    beams.remove(beam);

                    destroy.play(0.04, 0, 1.5, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm omitting the SpaceShip, Beam and Rock classes for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Look at `JavaFX's` [`AnimatinTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html). Go through this tutorial: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question,  I am currently using AnimationTimer.

Comment: The tutorial will explain how to use it correctly. I didn't notice you were already using it.

Comment: That shouldn't really be causing any performance problems, unless you have a large number of game objects (particularly rocks) at any one time.

Comment: An `AnimationTimer` is definitely the correct approach here; basically none of your code can/should be executed off the FX Application Thread, so there is nothing to do in a background thread. I have a similar example [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) which runs pretty smoothly for a reasonable number of objects.

Comment: @James_D I am using 20 rocks from the beginning and I've programmed them to bounce off the edges and also rebound off of each other and that takes up a lot of processing I guess.

Comment: It shouldn't do; you can see in the code I linked that this works just fine with 10 times that many objects. I recommend you profile your application to see what it consuming the processing time.

Comment: @James_D  There is a lot of collision detection code as well to detect collisions among the rocks themselves, between the space ship and the rocks and among the beams and the rocks. My laptop's running on an Intel 2.6GHz dual core processor and while running the game, task manager shows more than **70% of CPU usage** initially, which goes down gradually as I destroy the rocks.

Comment: 70% CPU usage?  Asteroids ran on an [Atari 2600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_2600), which cost $199 dollars and had a single core 8 bit 1.19MHz CPU.  A $35 [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) has a 1200MHz quad core 64 bit CPU and a 400 MHz video accelerator.  When your code for an old game runs inefficiently on modern hardware, it is time to rethink your algorithm.  As you discovered :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I profiled my code as suggested by James_D and found out that all the lag was being caused by the **Shape.intersect(Shape, Shape)** method, which I was using for more precise collision checking. I replaced that with the regular Bounds checking method and it runs smoothly now.